# Why am I flunking modulo subtraction?

Tags: language-agnostic

Oh god this must be so simple. I have a heading in range (0, 2π) and two points from which I get the heading in between. I must compare them to see if one is within a range of the other. What I've got so far is.

```
//get the angle
float angle = atan(here.x - there.x, here.y - there.y);

//atan2 uses (-pi, pi) range, convert to (0, 2pi)
if(angle < 0) angle += 2*pi;

//subtract them pesky headings
float diff = angle - givenAngle;

//a difference of 350 degrees really is a difference of 10 degrees
if(diff > pi) diff = 2*pi - diff;

//a difference of -10 degrees really is a difference of 10 degrees
if(diff < 0) diff *= -1;

//check if the point is in range of givenAngle
if(diff > fov) do_magic(diff - fov);
```

However, I get all sorts of issues when both angles wrap around to zero and I've been wasting way too much brainpower in solving this solved problem.

Where am I doing it wrong? How can I find the difference between two headings correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main problems was in this line:

```
float angle = atan(here.x - there.x, here.y - there.y);
```

It was kind of tricky to notice, but that's not the right argument order for [`atan`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/atan.xml) - even [the mathematical definition on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) takes the `y` component (sine) *before* the `x` component (cosine).

```
float angle = atan(here.y - there.y, here.x - there.x);
```

A second problem is that, as it turns out, `angle` was off by 180 degrees. In other words, instead of calculating `here - there`, I should be calculating `there - here`.

```
float angle = atan(there.y - here.y, there.x - here.x);
```

Add in [sverre's observation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690032/sverre) about the incorrect order of operations, and we have something that works much better:

```
float angle = atan(there.y - here.y, there.x - here.x);
if(angle < 0) angle += pi * 2; //use (0, 2pi) range, the same as angle
float diff = abs(angle - givenAngle);
if(diff > pi) diff = 2*pi - diff;
if(diff > fov) do_magic(diff - fov);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the order of your operations may be slightly wrong:

```
//a difference of 350 degrees really is a difference of 10 degrees
if(diff > pi) diff = 2*pi - diff;

//a difference of -10 degrees really is a difference of 10 degrees
if(diff < 0) diff *= -1;
```

This doesn't account for an diff of `-350`, but if you switch the statements it does:

```
//a difference of -10 degrees really is a difference of 10 degrees
if(diff < 0) diff *= -1;

//a difference of ±350 degrees really is a difference of 10 degrees
if(diff > pi) diff = 2*pi - diff;
```

Comment: This is probably a step in the right direction but not a full solution either :/

Comment: can you give some example values of `angle` and `givenAngle` where the result is not what you expected?

Comment: The problem was elsewhere, see my answer. Thank you so much.